# BCE Loss close to 0 but Training Accuracy still bad

Tags: pytorch, classification, loss, mlp

I am training a MLP using BinaryCrossentropy as a loss function. I have two classes (0 and 1) which are basically equally likely.

During the training phase, my loss is decreasing to almost 0 as I would expect it. However, what irritates me is that the Accuracy is super low. For my test dataset, it is 0.5 (meaning just random guessing) and even on my training dataset, it is only 0.6. How does a loss of 0 fit together with an accuracy of 0.6 only? Is there some concept I'm missing or is this caused by huge errors in my code?

Comment: It is difficult to say if "this caused by huge errors in my code" without any code.

Comment: Having a very low loss on training data doesn't necessarily mean your model will be good on unseen data. What might have happened in your case is overfitting, whereby your model has learned to handle the training points perfectly well, leading its training loss to diminish. This being done without your model being able to generalize and handle your test data better. It could be a matter of scaling your model or maybe your training is too long. Anyhow, it's hard to guess without the code and the train/validation loss logs...

Comment: Please post code specifically on how inputs to loss function are formatted. Likely your inputs are not formatted as the loss function expects them to be

Comment: For instance, for two classes, you should be predicting a single value for each data example. Predicting 2 values would be redundant

Comment: Thank you for you ideas. I also thought about overfitting, but then the accuracy on the training data would be much better, right? 0.6 on the training data is still pretty bad.